# Provision Web Part Page from Module with SetupPath?

Tags: feature-activation, web-part-page

Is it possible to provision a Web Part Page using a Module element with a SetupPath specified, rather than a Path specified?  For example, if I wanted to create a module to provision a page from: **TEMPLATE{LCID}\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS** (which I believe are the templates used when you Create a new Web Part Page from the SP Web Based interface using Site Actions > More Options > Pages > Web Part Page).

```
  <!-- from templates used from Web Part Page Create page (_layouts/spcf.aspx) -->
  <!-- TODO: dynamically determine LCID?? is there a replacement token that can be used?? -->
  <Module Name="SitePages" SetupPath="1033\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS\" >
    <File Path="spstd4.aspx" Url="SitePages/Brian_SMARTPGS.aspx">
    </File>
  </Module>
```

I get the "File" provisioned, and it shows in SPD when I view the contents of the SitePages Wiki Page Library, however, when I view using the AllItems.aspx view, I don't see it.  If I create the Web Part Page using the SP Web Based Interface, I do see it in AllItems.aspx.

I think the root of this is that the files get provisioned, and can be browsed, however they are stored as File, and not Wiki Page.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is possible.  I had to handle my Module element a bit differently.  The key was to add a List="119" (for the Wiki Page Library), a Url="SitePages" to the Module.  Then in the File elements, ensure Type="GhostableInLibrary" is set.

I found this resource which helped me come to this conclusion:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2009/02/25/custom-wiki-site-definition-with-custom-document-template-for-creating-wiki-pages.aspx

Here are some sample elements that you can use to try it out:

```
  <!-- from "Team Site" Site Template-->
  <Module Name="TeamSite" SetupPath="SiteTemplates\STS\" List="119" Url="SitePages" >
    <File Path="Default.aspx" Url="Brian_STS.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>

  <!-- from templates used from Web Part Page Create page (_layouts/spcf.aspx) -->
  <!-- TODO: dynamically determine LCID?? is there a replacement token that can be used?? -->
  <Module Name="SmartPages" SetupPath="1033\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS\" List="119" Url="SitePages" >
    <File Path="spstd4.aspx" Url="Brian_SMARTPGS.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >

    </File>
  </Module>


  <!-- from Wiki Page template -->
  <Module Name="Wiki" SetupPath="DocumentTemplates\" List="119" Url="SitePages" >
    <File Path="wkpstd.aspx" Url="Brian_Wiki.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >

    </File>
  </Module>
```